# Able to generate csv file, but they are not split into multiple columns, all columns are in first column

Tags: python, csv

I have the code below, which takes in a json file and then parses it to csv. My code works, but the issue is that instead of the csv having multiple columns (what I want), it lists all of the data under column 1 without any seperation. Not sure where I'm wrong in my code below:

```
#flattens and converts json to csv file
def json2csv():
    parse = format_json()
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    today_str = now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    outputFilePathCSV = 'datastream_log/'
    #outputs to given csv file
    with open('datastream_csv/'+'datastream:' + today_str + '.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
        filename.append(csv_file.name)
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter='\t')
        #appends headers to top row
        keylist = []
        for key in parse[1]:
            y = keylist.append(key)
        writer.writerow(keylist)
        #appends rows from dictionary
        for data, data_rec in parse.items():
            try:
                writer.writerow( list(data_rec.values()))
            except(KeyError, TypeError, AttributeError) as e:
                pass
json2csv()
```

Example of JSON:

```
{"target": {"icao_address": "8963BB", "timestamp": "2019-12-02T21:41:03Z", "altitude_baro": 3075, "heading": 235.0, "speed": 162.0, "latitude": 43.403778, "longitude": 77.139225, "callsign": "FDB1735", "vertical_rate": -960, "squawk_code": "0573", "collection_type": "terrestrial", "ingestion_time": "2019-12-02T21:41:07Z", "tail_number": "A6-FEY", "icao_actype": "B738", "flight_number": "FZ1735", "origin_airport_icao": "OMDB", "destination_airport_icao": "UAAA", "scheduled_departure_time_utc": "2019-12-02T17:30:00Z", "scheduled_departure_time_local": "2019-12-02T21:30:00", "scheduled_arrival_time_utc": "2019-12-02T21:50:00Z", "scheduled_arrival_time_local": "2019-12-03T03:50:00"}}
{"target": {"icao_address": "4CA4EF", "timestamp": "2019-12-02T21:41:06Z", "altitude_baro": 15125, "heading": 80.0, "speed": 290.0, "latitude": 53.56636, "longitude": -3.047137, "callsign": "RYR9ZN", "vertical_rate": -1080, "collection_type": "terrestrial", "ingestion_time": "2019-12-02T21:41:10Z", "tail_number": "EI-DPK", "icao_actype": "B738", "flight_number": "FR156", "origin_airport_icao": "EIDW", "destination_airport_icao": "EGNM", "scheduled_departure_time_utc": "2019-12-02T20:55:00Z", "scheduled_departure_time_local": "2019-12-02T20:55:00", "scheduled_arrival_time_utc": "2019-12-02T21:55:00Z", "scheduled_arrival_time_local": "2019-12-02T21:55:00", "estimated_arrival_time_utc": "2019-12-02T21:53:00Z", "estimated_arrival_time_local": "2019-12-02T21:53:00"}}
```

CSV image of what I get:

[image]

Comment: Probably your csv file reader isn't configured to read tabs as separator. Instead of using delimiter as `\t`, can you try using `,`?

Comment: What software do you use to _view_ the results? Does it recognize that the separator is a tab, not a comma?

Comment: Naga's delimiter recommendation worked. I completely forgot about the , - thanks a lot, if you answer it, I will upvote this answer.